# Is it possible to get this resultset using XPath?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I have some XML which I'm using javascript and XPath (1.0) to work with as a learning process. I can manage basic things but pulling it all together is having me pull my hair out.

My XML file contains multiple books formatted like this.

```
<bookstore>     <!-- Added by edit -->
    <book category="Fantasy &amp; Adventure" cover="paperback" released="true" special="true" homepage="true">
        <title>Belgariad 1: Pawn of Prophecy</title>
        <artwork>david-eddings-belgariad-1.jpg</artwork>
        <author>David Eddings</author>
        <year>2006</year>
        <price>7.99</price>
        <rating>
            <score>4</score>
            <amount>340</amount>
        </rating>
        <description>
            <short>An ancient prophecy &amp; and a maimed God...--nl--Long ago, the evil God Torak fought a war to obtain an object of immense power - the Orb of Aldur.But Torak was defeated and the Orb reclaimed by Belgarath the sorcerer.</short>
            <long>Garion, a young farm lad, loves the story when he first hears it from the old storyteller. But it has nothing to do with him. Or does it? For the stories also tell of a prophecy that must be fulfilled - a destiny handed down through the generations.--nl--And Torak is stirring again...</long>
        </description>
        <reviews>
            <review>
                <source>Anne McCaffrey</source>
                <text>Fabulous.</text>
            </review>
            <review>
                <source>Darren Shan</source>
                <text>Fun, exciting, intriguing fantasy in which the characters are as important as the quest and magical elements... immerse yourself and enjoy!</text>
            </review>
        </reviews>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

I am trying to get a set of nodes back containing title, artwork, price, description/short, rating/score and rating/amount. I can easily get title, artwork and price back using a predicate (see below) but I have tried every combination of self::, child::, descendant:: and so on for about 48 hours and I cannot get it to work.  Would someone be able to put me out of my misery and tell me if it's even possible?

The XPath I've got closest with is:

```
/bookstore/book[@special='true' and @homepage='true']/*[self::title | self::artwork | self::price]
```

Which gets me those 3 elements in order (title, artwork, price; title, artwork, price etc) but if I add anything like self::description/short or child::*/short I just get nothing returned for the description.

Worst case I can just access all the pieces separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element names are unique, you can use this simple approach with the `descendant-or-self::` axis:

```
/bookstore/book[@special='true' and @homepage='true']/descendant-or-self::*[self::title | self::artwork | self::price | self::short | self::score | self::amount]
```

Its output is:

```
Belgariad 1: Pawn of Prophecy 
david-eddings-belgariad-1.jpg 
7.99 
4 
340 
An ancient prophecy &amp; and a maimed God...--nl--Long ago, the evil God Torak fought a war to obtain an object of immense power - the Orb of Aldur.But Torak was defeated and the Orb reclaimed by Belgarath the sorcerer.
```

---

If they are not unique you need to specify the parent, using the `parent::` axis in a predicate:

```
/bookstore/book[@special='true' and @homepage='true']/descendant-or-self::*[self::title | self::artwork | self::price | self::short[parent::description] | self::score[parent::rating] | self::amount[parent::rating]]
```

The output should be the same in this example.

*Note that the order of the output is in source-file-order and not the order of the XPath expression.*

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it. Thanks a lot! I had tried descendant-or-self:: for the final 3 items but it didn't occur to me to use it before the predicate. A case of so close yet so far :(

Answer (score 1):

If your version of  xpath supports it, you can use the shorter expression:

```
/bookstore/book[@special='true'][@homepage='true']/(title, artwork, price, //short, //score, //amount)
```

Comment: I think half the issue I was having was because it was the 1.0 version so anything with parentheses like your suggestion just ends up with an error. I did come up with some solutions for 2.0 or above which worked in XPath test websites but just wouldn't on my own.